# Many instances in one call to db (sequelize)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Someone knows how I can create an instance in sequelize and their associations in one call to db?
I want to say:

```
const user = await User.create({name: 'Tom'});
const project = await Project.create({title: 'Yes'});
await user.addProject(project);
```

Can i do this in a single function? Because if I want to bulkCreate many users and project, I have to call db a lot of times.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Models have an association then you can use the `include` property to specify the model and then pass in the data for the call to `create()`, see the params here: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-create).

```js
const user = await User.create(
  { 
    name: 'Tom', 
    project: {
      title: 'Yes',
    },
  }, 
  {
    include: {
      model: Project,
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me a lot! And how it works with bulkCreate? Can you answer that to me please?